# How to delete random n files from directory?

Tags: 16.04, files, delete

I have a uploads directory and I want to delete random 1000 images from it. How can I do that with command ?

I am able to delete single with `rm` but it tooks long.. Is there any way to bulk delete on ubuntu ?

Comment: what is/are the file extensions for the image files?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen jpg files

Comment: @PerlDuck, I can't any process in server, there is no available storage. I need to create some space.. so yes

Comment: @PerlDuck Nope I don't want to delete all of them, just random 1000 images

Comment: @PerlDuck is it possible ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
find /uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | \
        head -z -n 1000 | xargs -0 rm
```

The `find` command finds any files (`-type f`) named `*.jpg` (`-name "*.jpg"`) in the directory `/uploads` and does NOT recurse into subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`) (which it usually does). It then prints the filenames with `\0` as a separator in-between. This is necessary as the filenames might contain weird characters (like spaces and such).

That output is fed into the `head` command. It reads the first 1000 "lines" (`-n 1000`) which are separated by `\0` (`-z`).

Eventually these 1000 "lines" (=filenames) are fed into `xargs` which as well expects the "lines" to be separated by `\0` (`-0`) and then executes `rm` with all those 1000 lines as parameters.

---

If you just want to preview the result, change the command to

```
find /uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | \
    head -z -n 1000 | xargs -0 echo rm
```

i.e. replace `xargs … rm` with `xargs … echo rm`. Maybe also replace the `1000` with `10` for the preview.

---

Disclaimer: I don't know *how* the files printed by `find` are sorted, but at least it is not some apparent attribute (like name or age) and *looks* random. If you really want to pick 1000 random files, you would need to insert a `sort -R` to sort randomly (again with `-z` for the `\0` delimiter):

```
find /uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | \
    sort -z -R | head -z -n 1000 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: this not an answer, no.. this is beyond the answer. this is kind of masterpiece :) thank you brotha :)

Comment: @HasanTıngır You are welcome. Thank you. :-) I appreciate that and am glad I could help you! I enjoyed answering and actually _one-line-answers_ (like just the `find ...` command) aren't well received on AU. Without an explanation nobody without adequate knowledge can tell whether the answer is right/wrong/malicious or how to adapt it to their own problem.

Comment: really greate answer with detailed explain.